# ASP.NET incorrect behaviour when on multiple pages

Tags: asp.net, caching, calendar

On the site I am currently developing I have a (for now) 2 pages each with 2 calendar controls displaying course dates, one for beginners courses and one for advanced courses.

When initially navigating to page1 the controls work fine (when clicking).

BUT when navigating to page2 the controls (when clicking) either the don't work or they actually navigate back to page1.

It is as if the calendar control gets cached or something like that and only remember where it was first used on the site.

I have also tried disabling all caching on the pages to no avail.

I DO NOT want to use the javascript calendar popup as you physically have to click a button to make it show.

HTML for first page:

```
<div class="divcol">
    <asp:Calendar ID="calBegEventDecor" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#2d0231" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="1" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#5b0462" Height="200px" Width="220px" Font-Bold="True" OnDayRender="calBegEventDecor_DayRender">
        <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#9e06ac" ForeColor="#ffffff" Height="1px" />
        <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#9e06ac" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
        <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="#5b0462" BorderColor="#5b0462" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#ffffff" Height="25px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#f9cefd" />
    </asp:Calendar>
</div>
<div class="divcol">
    <asp:Calendar ID="calAdvEventDecor" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#2d0231" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="1" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#5b0462" Height="200px" Width="220px" Font-Bold="True" OnDayRender="calAdvEventDecor_DayRender">
        <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#9e06ac" ForeColor="#ffffff" Height="1px" />
        <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#9e06ac" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
        <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="#5b0462" BorderColor="#5b0462" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#ffffff" Height="25px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#f9cefd" />
        </asp:Calendar>
</div>
```

Code for 1st page:

```
public partial class PlanningCourses : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private List<DateTime> beginnerCourseDates = new List<DateTime>();
    private List<DateTime> advancedCourseDates = new List<DateTime>();

    private double beginnersEventDecorationSingle = 4200.00;
    private double beginnersEventDecorationGroup = 3700.00;
    private double advancedEventDecorationSingle = 9450.00;
    private double advancedsEventDecorationGroup = 8900.00;

    public double BeginnersEventDecorationGroup
    {
        get { return beginnersEventDecorationGroup; }
        set { beginnersEventDecorationGroup = value; }
    }
    public double BeginnersEventDecorationSingle
    {
        get { return beginnersEventDecorationSingle; }
        set { beginnersEventDecorationSingle = value; }
    }
    public double AdvancedEventDecorationGroup
    {
        get { return advancedsEventDecorationGroup; }
        set { advancedsEventDecorationGroup = value; }
    }
    public double AdvancedEventDecorationSingle
    {
        get { return advancedEventDecorationSingle; }
        set { advancedEventDecorationSingle = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Suppose that you have the following list of dates below
        beginnerCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/5"));
        beginnerCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/19"));

        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/6"));
        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/7"));
        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/8"));
        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/20"));
        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/21"));
        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/22"));
    }

    protected void calBegEventDecor_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set Default properties
        //if the date is in the past, disable it and mark it gray else just disable it
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()) < Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(217, 217, 217); //System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        else if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()) == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
        {
            e.Cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            e.Cell.BorderWidth = 2;
            e.Cell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(91, 4, 98);
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(242, 133, 250); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        //Now loop through the list of dates and make it
        //Selectable
        foreach (DateTime d in beginnerCourseDates)
        {
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(d.ToShortDateString()) >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
            {
                calBegEventDecor.SelectedDates.Add(d);
                if (e.Day.IsSelected)
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(158, 6, 172); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 204, 153); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void calAdvEventDecor_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set Default properties
        //if the date is in the past, disable it and mark it gray else just disable it
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()) < Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(217, 217, 217); //System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        else if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()) == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
        {
            e.Cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            e.Cell.BorderWidth = 2;
            e.Cell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(91, 4, 98);
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(242, 133, 250); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        //Now loop through the list of dates and make it
        //Selectable
        foreach (DateTime d in advancedCourseDates)
        {
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(d.ToShortDateString()) >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
            {
                calAdvEventDecor.SelectedDates.Add(d);
                if (e.Day.IsSelected)
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(158, 6, 172); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 204, 153); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }

}
```

HTML for 2nd page:

```
<div class="divcol">
    <asp:Calendar ID="calBegBalloonDecor" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#2d0231" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="1" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#5b0462" Height="200px" Width="220px" Font-Bold="True" OnDayRender="calBegBalloonDecor_DayRender">
        <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#9e06ac" ForeColor="#ffffff" Height="1px" />
        <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#9e06ac" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
        <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="#5b0462" BorderColor="#5b0462" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#ffffff" Height="25px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#f9cefd" />
    </asp:Calendar>
</div>
<div class="divcol">
    <asp:Calendar ID="calAdvBalloonDecor" runat="server" BackColor="White" BorderColor="#2d0231" BorderWidth="1px" 
        CellPadding="1" DayNameFormat="Shortest" Font-Names="Verdana" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#5b0462" Height="200px" Width="220px" Font-Bold="True" OnDayRender="calAdvBalloonDecor_DayRender">
        <DayHeaderStyle BackColor="#9e06ac" ForeColor="#ffffff" Height="1px" />
        <NextPrevStyle Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
        <OtherMonthDayStyle ForeColor="#999999" />
        <SelectedDayStyle BackColor="#9e06ac" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="#ffffff" />
        <SelectorStyle BackColor="#99CCCC" ForeColor="#336666" />
        <TitleStyle BackColor="#5b0462" BorderColor="#5b0462" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Bold="True" Font-Size="10pt" ForeColor="#ffffff" Height="25px" HorizontalAlign="Center" />
        <WeekendDayStyle BackColor="#f9cefd" />
    </asp:Calendar>
</div>
```

Code for 2nd page:

```
public partial class BalloonCourses : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    private List<DateTime> beginnerCourseDates = new List<DateTime>();
    private List<DateTime> advancedCourseDates = new List<DateTime>();

    private double beginnersBalloonDecorSingle = 4700.00;
    private double beginnersBalloonDecorGroup = 4200.00;
    private double advancedBalloonDecorSingle = 6950.00;
    private double advancedsBalloonDecorGroup = 6450.00;

    public double BeginnersBalloonDecorGroup
    {
        get { return beginnersBalloonDecorGroup; }
        set { beginnersBalloonDecorGroup = value; }
    }
    public double BeginnersBalloonDecorSingle
    {
        get { return beginnersBalloonDecorSingle; }
        set { beginnersBalloonDecorSingle = value; }
    }
    public double AdvancedBalloonDecorGroup
    {
        get { return advancedsBalloonDecorGroup; }
        set { advancedsBalloonDecorGroup = value; }
    }
    public double AdvancedBalloonDecorSingle
    {
        get { return advancedBalloonDecorSingle; }
        set { advancedBalloonDecorSingle = value; }
    }

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Suppose that you have the following list of dates below
        beginnerCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/12"));
        beginnerCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/26"));

        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/13"));
        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/14"));
        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/27"));
        advancedCourseDates.Add(Convert.ToDateTime("2016/09/28"));
    }

    protected void calBegBalloonDecor_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set Default properties
        //if the date is in the past, disable it and mark it gray else just disable it
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()) < Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(217, 217, 217); //System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        else if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()) == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
        {
            e.Cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            e.Cell.BorderWidth = 2;
            e.Cell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(91, 4, 98);
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(242, 133, 250); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        //Now loop through the list of dates and make it
        //Selectable
        foreach (DateTime d in beginnerCourseDates)
        {
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(d.ToShortDateString()) >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
            {
                calBegBalloonDecor.SelectedDates.Add(d);
                if (e.Day.IsSelected)
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(158, 6, 172); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 204, 153); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    protected void calAdvBalloonDecor_DayRender(object sender, DayRenderEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set Default properties
        //if the date is in the past, disable it and mark it gray else just disable it
        e.Day.IsSelectable = false;
        if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()) < Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(217, 217, 217); //System.Drawing.Color.Gray;
        else if (Convert.ToDateTime(e.Day.Date.ToShortDateString()) == Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
        {
            e.Cell.BorderStyle = BorderStyle.Solid;
            e.Cell.BorderWidth = 2;
            e.Cell.BorderColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(91, 4, 98);
            e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(242, 133, 250); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        }
        //Now loop through the list of dates and make it
        //Selectable
        foreach (DateTime d in advancedCourseDates)
        {
            if (Convert.ToDateTime(d.ToShortDateString()) >= Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString()))
            {
                calAdvBalloonDecor.SelectedDates.Add(d);
                if (e.Day.IsSelected)
                {
                    e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(158, 6, 172); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //e.Cell.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(255, 204, 153); //System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                    //e.Day.IsSelectable = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: please post some code. else we cant help

Comment: Thanks. I have added my HTML and code.

Answer (score 0):

Controls typically don't redirect anywhere. Most likely you have a code in the click event that does that redirect. To troubleshoot get rid of that code on page 2 and see if it still redirects. If, suppose, the controls were "cached", they should continue to redirect without the code. If page behaves differently (no redirect without code) - enable the code again and check it line by line. It can be that you keep dates selected on page 1 in a session, and on page 2 you check that session again and then redirect.

Comment: Thanks. I have added my HTML and code. Now I don't do any redirects in any click events. I only highlight certain dates.

Comment: What should I see in that code? I created a test project with 2 pages and paste your code - page2 works as expected - selected dates were highlighted. What is the problem?

Comment: The dates highlight fine as they should on both pages. If you change the month on one page i.e. change to October or November then navigate to the second page and try do the same then that is where the problem comes in. I am then back on the first page looking at the calendar controls of the first page.

Comment: I confirm, I don't have any issue with changing a month. I tried as suggested to change September to October on one calendar, changed url to page2 and change calendar there to November, changed url back to page1 - I see September again and I'm able to change it to any month. I tried with only one and I tried with both calendars.